# Add bash aliases to python package commands

Tags: python, bash, shell, setup.py

I have written a small python module that provides commands as such:

```
cheesy (ls|list)
```

I would like to alias `cheesy ls` to `ch-ls`. But I don't want to add this manually to bash_rc, but create an alias to the environment automatically when the package `setup.py` installs.

I am wondering if I can add a bash function with the package to do so and add it to the shell using python.